# error: ReferenceError: interaction is not defined

Tags: discord, discord.js

I'm trying to add more than one into this switch thing, it works with one, but adding more just adds gets me this error "interaction is not defined"

game1 & network is querying to
const { game1db, networkdb} = require('../mysql/mysqlquery.js')

How do I solve this "interaction is not defined", I'd be grateful for all the help
Code:

```
const run = async (client, interaction) => {
    if (!interaction.guild) return;

    let platform = interaction.options.get('platform').value
    let username = interaction.options.getString("username")
    console.log(platform)
    const hasRole = interaction.member.roles.cache.some(r => r.name === "Support")
    if (!hasRole) return;

    await interaction.deferReply({ ephemeral: true });
    await wait(4000);
    switch (platform) {
        case "network":
            try {
                networkdb(`${username}`, (err, result) => {
                    if (err) {
                        interaction.followUp({ content: result, ephemeral: true });
                    } else {
                        interaction.followUp({ content: result, ephemeral: true });
                    }
                })
            } catch (error) {
                interaction.followUp({ content: `error: ${error}`, ephemeral: true });
            }
            break;
        case "game1":
            try {
                game1db(`${username}`, (err, result) => {
                    if (err) {
                        interaction.followUp({ content: result, ephemeral: true });
                    } else {
                        interaction.followUp({ content: result, ephemeral: true });
                    }
                })
            } catch (error) {
                interaction.followUp({ content: `error: ${error}`, ephemeral: true });
            }
            break;
        default:
            interaction.followUp({ content: `${platform} is not supported yet`, ephemeral: true });
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `client` isn't the interaction and `interaction` is undefined because only 1 parameter is being supplied

Comment: Yeah, interaction worked when i didnt use if and cases n that, but now it dont work